# Maven: How to include a dependency with a specific build profile?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a project where I use Spring Boot 1.1.2.RELEASE which uses Spring 4.1.5, and Spring HATEOAS 0.10.0.RELEASE which uses Spring 4.0.9. This causes some dependency problems like the infamous `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.SmartInitializingSingleton`.

I dug into the POM of `spring-hateoas` and found that there are different profiles defined, one of them being `spring41` which depends on Spring 4.1.5. Is it possible to select this profile in my `<dependency>` section, or do I have to exclude the Spring dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

Automatically selecting a profile for a build isn't easy. You can enable it by default in your personal `settings.xml` but that breaks the build for everyone who doesn't have the same file.

You can't enable a profile in the POM of the project.

With Maven 3.3, you can add the profile to `${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/maven.config`. Since this file is part of the project, it's easy to share. You can use the [Maven Enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) to make sure everyone uses a Maven version with actually uses the file.

If you can't use 3.3, then your best bet is to exclude the dependencies. If you have a parent POM, then you can use a `dependencyManagement` element to do it for all POMs in the reactor build.

Comment: I went the easier route excluding `org.springframework.*` in my `spring-hateoas` dependency.